# d/d(rsin(theta)cos(phi)) = ???

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics, polar-coordinates, quantum-mechanics

What does $\frac{d}{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}$ equal? I am very confused because if the function were in the numerator, not the denominator, it would make perfect sense to me (i.e., $\frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{dr}$ or $\frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{d\theta}$ or $\frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{d\phi)}$, but since it is $\frac{d}{d(function)}$, I don't know what to do with this. Moreover, I know what the solution is, but no clue how it is obtained.

Solution is apparently $\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\frac{d}{dr} + \frac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\frac{d}{d\theta} - \frac{1}{r}
\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sin(\theta)}\frac{d}{d\phi}$

I notice that the solution is similar to $\frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{dr} + \frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{d\theta} + \frac{d(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))}{d\phi}$, but not exactly.

Comment: This notation is, in my opinion, unfortunately the notation people use for the chain rule. In one variable, if you define $h(x) = f(g(x))$, then under this notation, one would write $$\frac{d}{dx}h(x) = \frac{d}{dg(x)}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

Comment: @AndrewZhang but in all of the functions you just wrote there, there is a function in the numerator, i.e. a function that we are taking the derivative of. In this problem, there is not... So confusing.

Comment: This is unreadable. Please use LaTeX/MathJax.

Comment: Please any user edit this....im not able to understand what to edit and whatnot

Answer (score 1):

Just slug through the [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) change of variables, likely in your textbook. Note your derivatives are all ***partial derivatives***, and here you are meant to keep *x,y* constant!

You know that
$$
x= r\sin\theta \cos\phi,
$$
so
$$
\partial_x= \partial_x r ~\partial_r + \partial_x \theta ~\partial_\theta + \partial_x \phi ~ \partial_\phi \\
=\frac{x}{r} ~\partial_r +\frac{1}{r}\cos\theta\cos\phi   ~\partial_\theta  
-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\sin\phi}{\sin\theta}  ~ \partial_\phi~~,$$
your very expression, as $x/r=\sin\theta ~\cos\phi $. Note the [inverse Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) $J^{-1}$.